# Twitter API User timeline stream in python tweepy

Tags: python, tweepy

The code below is functional and it streams tweets and stores them in a JSON file. I am running it on a virtual machine since I want to collect 2 months worth of data. However, for some reason, the code stopped running after around 48 hours with no error. Is this a tweepy limitation ( streaming rate or something) or should I check my connection:

```
import os 

import sys 

from tweepy import API 

from tweepy import OAuthHandler 



consumer_key = ''

consumer_secret = ''

access_token = ''

access_secret = ''

auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret) 

auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret) 

def get_twitter_client(): 

  """Setup Twitter API client Return: tweepy.API object  """ 

  auth = get_twitter_auth() 

  client = API(auth) 

  return client 
from tweepy import Stream

from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
```

class MyListener(StreamListener):

```
def on_data(self, data):
    try:
        with open('strategyand_user.json', 'a') as f:
            f.write(data)
            return True
    except BaseException as e:
        print("Error on_data: %s" % str(e))
    return True

def on_error(self, status):
    print(status)
    return True


twitter_stream = Stream(auth, MyListener())

twitter_stream.filter(follow=['xxxxxxx'])
```

Comment: I guess there are not that much useful answers related to unexpected and odd Tweepy errors @Moh'd Hmayed